# no warning for pointer to subclassed struct of wrong size

Tags: c++

I was writing a helper class to concisely initialize `struct pollfd`s, and lamenting that I could not add an additional member in the helper subclass class, so I tried and to my surprise it compiled without any warnings.  The runtime behavior is wrong as I expected, but why can I even get this far?

I would expect pointers to classes of different sizes to at least a require a cast;  is there a compiler flag that will detect this error?  I'm compiling with g++ 9.4.0, no additional flags specified.

Code:

```
#include <poll.h>
#include <vector>

struct pollin : public pollfd {
    int extra;  ///< additional field in derived class.
    pollin(int infd) {
        fd = infd;
        events = POLLIN;
    }
};


int main(int ac, char **av) {
    std::vector<pollin> fds;
    fds.emplace_back(5);
    fds.emplace_back(6);
    poll(fds.data(), fds.size(), 0);
    return 0;
}
```

The as-expected wrong runtime behavior can be seen by running with `strace`:

```
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=0, events=POLLPRI|POLLOUT}], 2, 0) = 2 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLNVAL}, {fd=0, revents=POLLOUT}])
```

Comment: Welcome to the bad parts of C++.

Comment: deriving from a class to initialize its members is a bad idea.

Comment: You'd be surprised to know how few errors a C++ compiler is actually required to diagnose (issue warnings or errors for). A huge amount of incorrect code just results in [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) which gives the compiler permission to do *anything* and it is not obligated to diagnose it. It is *your* responsibility as a programmer to ensure your program is correct, you cannot rely on the compiler pointing out your errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't try to offset from it, a pointer to a derived class can be directly substituted for a pointer to its parent without a cast.  This is the standard practice to allow for polymorphism.  In fact, if you had done `poll(fds.data(), 1, 0)` everything would have worked and been well-defined.

Its when you try to treat a pointer to the first element of an array of derived objects like a pointer to the first element of an array of parent objects that you run into problems.  The two are *not* interchangeable in that situation.

The issue here is that the compiler has no idea what `poll` does.  When it's compiling your `main` function all it sees is `poll`'s signature, so it doesn't know that `poll` will treat the pointer you passed it as pointing to the first element of an array.

---

I'm actually quite surprised that [none of the major compilers offer a warning](https://godbolt.org/z/qM61GYxqd) for using a pointer to the first element of an array of derived objects as a pointer to the first element of an array of parent objects, even when everything is easily visible.

Comment: pointer is pointer; after the array decays or pointer is created, th compiler has no idea about the source. That's why use of raw pointers is always a red flag. With C API, yoi need wrappers to convert such silent bugs into compile time errors.

Answer (score 2):

> I would expect pointers to classes of different sizes to at least a require a cast;

No, conversions to public base classes can *always* be done implicitly and that is not something that should generally produce warnings. Sizes are completely irrelevant. The principle for inheritance is object-oriented programming. What matters is only the API for the individual object. It isn't concerned with memory layout. Inheriting publicly from `pollfd` should mean that every `pollin` *is a* `pollfd` and is able to be used as such. But this is a principle for individual objects, not arrays of objects.

If you do not want to allow implicit conversion to base class pointers, then inherit privately:

```
struct pollin : private pollfd {
    int extra;  ///< additional field in derived class.
    pollin(int infd) {
        fd = infd;
        events = POLLIN;
    }
};
```

If `poll` was a C++ API it could be a template and take a begin and end iterator or a `std::span`, so that the correct value type could be verified. But it is a C API, so it isn't really going to consider the inheritance model of C++, nor would it be able to.